# Make SCSS sourcemaps work in Webpack 2 using extract-text-webpack-plugin?

Tags: webpack, source-maps, webpack-2

I'm starting to configure my first Webpack v2 task manager. This is the first time I'm using Webpack.

I'm using extract-text-webpack-plugin to have an external CSS file.

My problem is that I don't know how to setup sourcemaps for my SCSS file.

Is anyone have a solution for that ?

Thanks a lot!

---

Here is my Webpack.config.js file :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader','postcss-loader','sass-loader'],
          publicPath: '/dist',
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Project Demo',
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: false
      },
      hash: true,
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
    new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin({
      sound: false,
      suppressSuccess: false
    }),
    new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      server: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
      // proxy: {
      //   target: 'http://localhost:3000',
      //   ws: true
      // }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: true,
      options: {
        postcss: [
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 4 version', 'Explorer >= 10', 'Android >= 4']
          })
        ]
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename:'app.css',
      disable:false,
      allChunks:true
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable `sourceMap` in `sass-loader` and `css-loader` as shown in [`sass-loader` Source maps](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#source-maps). Your `.scss` rule would look like this:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
      'postcss-loader',
      { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
    ],
    publicPath: '/dist',
  })
}
```

Comment: I was having a lot of trouble figuring out how to pass the `sourceMap` property to the loaders, so thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as OP and based on Michael Jungos suggestion I found that the following snippet worked out. Basically I used the snippet provided by Michael but I had to extend the `postcss-loader`-line a bit and then i omitted `publicPath: '/dist'`.

Finally my solution looks like this:

`{
  test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
  loader: extractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
      {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {sourceMap: 'inline'}},
      {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}
    ]
  })
}`